# How to delete record having foreign key constraint?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Here I have `Person` and `PersonFileUpload` table. The `PersonFileUpload` table have `PersonId` as foreign key which primary in `Person` table.

Now to I want to delete person from person table and all respective PersonId from PersonFileUpload on single delete.

Now to do this I tried to use `Include()` with person like

```
var getModel = uow.Repository<Person>().GetAll()
                                       .Where(x => x.PersonId == id)
                                       .Include(x => x.PersonFileUpload)
                                       .FirstOrDefault();
```

Now the problem is that it shows in

```
uow.Repository<Person>().GetAll()
                        .Where(x => x.PersonId == id)
                        .Include(x => x.PersonFileUpload)
                        .FirstOrDefault()
```

saying

> IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no accessible extension method 'Include' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is my code for the delete operation:

```
    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _dbset.AsEnumerable();
    }

    public Person GetPersonByIdForDelete(int id)
    {
        var getModel = uow.Repository<Person>().GetAll()
                                               .Where(x => x.PersonId == id)
                                               .Include(x => x.PersonFileUpload)
                                               .FirstOrDefault();           
        return getModel;
    }

    public void DeletePerson(int id)
    {
        var getModel = GetPersonByIdForDelete(id);
        uow.Repository<Person>().Delete(getModel);
        uow.Commit();
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you have returned IEnumerable in GetAll - bad idea to have such repositories. Also Include is for loading data, not deleting. You have to define Cascade Delete for your entities.

Comment: If you are using repositories, `Include` should be within the repository method; the `IQueryable` should not be exposed.

Answer (score 0):

For delete operation you don't need to `.Include()` child entities in your query. What you are trying to achieve can very easily be done with cascade delete feature - when a parent entity (`Person`) is deleted, the related children (`PersonFileUpload`) are deleted automatically. All you need to do is tell EF, when you configure the relationship, that you want cascade deletion for this relation. The rest is handled by the database.

Configure the relationship between `Person` and `PersonFileUpload` as -

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasMany(p => p.PersonFileUpload)
    .WithOne(p => p.Person)
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.PersonId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

If you do not have a `Person` navigation property in `PersonFileUpload` model, then you can leave the `.WithOne()` empty, like -

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasMany(p => p.PersonFileUpload)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.PersonId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

The delete method in your `Person` repository should look like -

```
public void Delete(int id)
{
    var person = _dbset.Where(x => x.PersonId == id).FirstOrDefault();
    _dbset.Remove(person);
}
```

Now you can delete a `Person` simply with -

```
uow.Repository<Person>().Delete(id);
uow.Commit();
```

and all the related `PersonFileUpload` will be deleted automatically.

Answer (score 0):

the code you were written should be better.

first you should change `GetPersonByIdForDelete()` and Delete `Include()`:

```
public Person GetPersonByIdForDelete(int id)
    {
        var getModel = uow.Repository<Person>().GetAll()
                                               .Where(x => x.PersonId == id)
                                               .FirstOrDefault();           
        return getModel;
    }
```

then you add another class to find related `PersonFileUpload`:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetPersonFileUploadByPersonIdForDelete(int id)
    {
        var getModel = uow.Repository<PersonFileUpload>().GetAll()
                                               .Where(x => x.PersonId == id).ToList();
        return getModel;
    }
```

and finally change your last method:

```
public void DeletePerson(int id)
    {
        var getModel = GetPersonByIdForDelete(id);
        uow.Repository<Person>().Delete(getModel);
        var getFileUploads = GetPersonFileUploadByPersonIdForDelete(id);
        foreach(var file in getFileUploads)
        {
         uow.Repository<PersonFileUpload>().Delete(file);
        }
        uow.Commit();
    }
```